# Change displayed url for a custom one using AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, url, url-routing

I have this piece of code in the nav bar

```
<li><a href=#products?scrollTo=products">Products</a></li>
```

This in the controller

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (newRoute, oldRoute) {
$location.hash($routeParams.scrollTo);
$anchorScroll();
});
```

and this in the config

```
$routeProvider.when('/products', { templateUrl: '../pages/home/home.html',
controller : 'mainController' });
```

It does work as expected, since it scrolls to the place the #products div is located even if I am not in the home page. (returning to the home page and scrolling down automatically).

Now, in the URL it says /products?scrollTo=products#products

Is there a way to change that for something more like www.home.com or www.home.com/products?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the hash to $anchorScroll and it will go there without adding it to the URL.

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (newRoute, oldRoute) {
    $anchorScroll($routeParams.scrollTo);
});
```

Comment: seems like this part <li><a href=#products?scrollTo=products">Products</a></li> is the one making the url, since I did as you suggested and I still have the "weird" url, but now the page does not scroll to the desired section

Comment: Sometimes you have to wrap calls to $anchorScroll in a timeout with something like: .$timeout(() => { $anchorScroll("tr_" + id) }, 0)